# Datasheet view allow incorrect values

Tags: 2010, list

I have a list with 7 fields, I use to upload a large amount of rows using datasheet view (copy and paste from excel), one of that fields is a Date (date format), but sometimes I want need to put some text in that field, is their any way of allow that text to be insert but mark that row as a error to be treated ?

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: are you able to copy data in list using datasheet view? did the below answer helps you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not simply paste the wrong data to field which type is not DateTime.

You need to make that column as string but after that you can not check if the correct date is entered to that column or not as it is going to accept the date as string